# My gecko won't open her eyes

Tags: health, geckos

My coleonyx gecko stopped opening her eyes about a week ago. She's opened them about 3 times in that time but its only been for a few seconds and then they're shut again.

She's not able to eat because of this. I've tried feeding her meal worms and she walks over them, turns her head, and now closes her eyes.
She's starving now.

I tried force feeding her a liquid mix but I got scared when she started coughing. The next day she was really skinny. I don't understand how she couldn't lost half her tail fat overnight.

So I tried researching and I'm accepting that she's dying but I really would like to save her or at least know why she's been the way she is. She's over 5 years old, I don't know her exact age because shes wild caught and the average span for coleonyx was 5-8 years.

She's been having issues for the past few months, I've posted before about them with a better order of events and better grammar. I can't get her to a vet, We don't have the money to drive her there and pay (I don't know how much it costs but my mom says she can't afford it.)

Comment: Sorry to hear about your gecko. If you cannot afford to go to a vet, you have a few options. You could look into something online, google for a free phone/online pet advice in your area or the Humane Society? Good luck